# Why is the mean larger than the max in this array?

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I have found myself with a very confusing array in Python. There following is the output from iPython when I work with it (with the pylab flag):

```
In [1]: x = np.load('x.npy')

In [2]: x.shape
Out[2]: (504000,)

In [3]: x
Out[3]: 
array([ 98.20354462,  98.26583099,  98.26529694, ...,  98.20297241,
        98.19876862,  98.29492188], dtype=float32)

In [4]: min(x), mean(x), max(x)
Out[4]: (97.950058, 98.689438, 98.329773)
```

I have no idea what is going on. Why is the mean() function providing what is obviously the wrong answer?

I don't even know where to begin to debug this problem.

I am using Python 2.7.6.

---

I would be willing to share the `.npy` file if necessary.

Comment: It seems that this would be difficult to answer without having access to `x`. Perhaps try to provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can replicate the problem? Also, where are your `min`, `mean`, and `max` functions coming from? Are they the numpy functions?

Comment: I have given you a proper minimal example. Hopefully this is OK.

Comment: I reverted your edit because it was unhelpful. I have tried creating new arrays and different vectors, and they all seem to work right. I merely happen to be in possession of a very specific `.npy` that seems to be problematic.

This isn't a problem that can be explained away with a minimal example, there isn't one.

Comment: @NikhilMahajan The minimal example reproduces the error reliably. I'm not "explaining it away", I'm giving a more generic way to test this. Look at pv.'s answer; that manages to give a helpful hint that the problem is fixed by allowing him to run the code himself.

Comment: Thanks. My mistake. I attempted to make an array myself and failed to get the wrong answer, which is why I did not think the minimal example helped because it did not, in fact, reproduce the problem for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably due to accumulated rounding error in computing mean(). float32 relative precision is ~ 1e-7, and you have 500000 elements -> ~ 5% rounding in direct computation of sum().

The algorithm for computing sum() and mean() is more sophisticated (pairwise summation) in the latest Numpy version 1.9.0:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.9.0'
>>> x = numpy.random.random(500000).astype("float32") + 300
>>> min(x), numpy.mean(x), max(x)
(300.0, 300.50024, 301.0)
```

In the meanwhile, you may want to use higher-precision accumulator type: `numpy.mean(x, dtype=numpy.float64)`

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the problem. I will upgrade my NumPy as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I have included a snippet from the `np.mean.__doc__` below. You should try using `np.mean(x, dtype=np.float64)`.

```
-----
The arithmetic mean is the sum of the elements along the axis divided
by the number of elements.

Note that for floating-point input, the mean is computed using the
same precision the input has.  Depending on the input data, this can
cause the results to be inaccurate, especially for `float32` (see
example below).  Specifying a higher-precision accumulator using the
`dtype` keyword can alleviate this issue.

In single precision, `mean` can be inaccurate:

>>> a = np.zeros((2, 512*512), dtype=np.float32)
>>> a[0, :] = 1.0
>>> a[1, :] = 0.1
>>> np.mean(a)
0.546875

Computing the mean in float64 is more accurate:

>>> np.mean(a, dtype=np.float64)
0.55000000074505806
```